# Make API queries - two methods failing

Tags: api, rest, apiv4

I'm trying to query my data for records with a given firstname/lastname pair (see [Map firstname-lastname pairs to IDs](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40627/map-firstname-lastname-pairs-to-ids) for some previous context) using a couple different methods, and failing.

### API4

The first way is using `cv` and some PHP code:

```
<?php

    $result = civicrm_api4('Contact', 'get', [
        'select' => ['id'],
        'where' => [['first_name', '=', 'Ken']],
        'limit' => 2,
    ]);
    echo $result->count(), "\n";
```

invoked via `` sudo -u daemon `which cv` scr my_script.php ``.

This prints `0`, though there are several records in my database with the first name `'Ken'`.

### REST API

The second way I've tried is to hit the REST API through some Python code, like so:

```
import requests

args = dict(
    entity='Contact',
    action='get',
    json='{"sequential":1,"return":"id","first_name":"Ken"}',
    api_key='my-api-key',
    key='my-site-key'
)

result = requests.get('http://my-site/modules/contrib/civicrm/extern/rest.php', params=args)
```

This gives me:

```
b'Could not load the settings file at: /bitnami/drupal/modules/contrib/civicrm/../..//default/civicrm.settings.php\n'
```

so I'm thinking my REST API might not quite be functional?  My settings file is at `/bitnami/drupal/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php`, which is not what it seems to be looking for.

### Question

How can I get one of these methods working?

### Details

I'm using CiviCRM 5.42.1 on Drupal 7.82.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `cv` call either turn off the permission check or specify a user to run with.

So either:

```
<?php
    $result = civicrm_api4('Contact', 'get', [
        'checkPermissions' => FALSE,
        'select' => ['id'],
        'where' => [['first_name', '=', 'Ken']],
        'limit' => 2,
    ]);
    echo $result->count(), "\n";
```

or

```
sudo -u daemon `which cv` scr -U admin my_script.php
```

where `admin` is a CMS user with appropriate powers.

FYI, with APIv3 `check_permissions` defaults to 0 whereas APIv4 `checkPermissions` defaults to True.